# NodeJS to Webservice .NET

Tags: .net, node.js, web-services

I have a server with Node.js and webservice in .NET to call the DB. I use superagent in Node.js to call the method in webservice.  The body of the request is a JSON text. Everything works fine. However, the request fail when the data contain some character like `'`.

I use `JSON.stringify()` to contruct the JSON. When the data contains `'`, the server in .NET fails and doesn't recognize the request. In Node.js, I do:

```
var request = require('superagent');
request
  .post(metodo)
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
  .send(data)
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .end(function (http_res) {

    if (http_res.ok && http_res.statusCode != '404') {
      // console.log(" :: " + JSON.stringify(http_res.body.d));
      callback(0, http_res.body);
    } else {
      console.log(http_res.statusCode + ' ' + metodo + " :: ERROR");
      callback(500, '');
    }
  });
```

In this case, I get 500 response. How I can to transform my string JSON in any format to accept the web service?

Thanks

Comment: Can you take a packet capture so we can see what is actually sent over the wire?  I suspect the problem is on the .NET side of things in parsing JSON.

Comment: something like {"var" : "value string with double quote " in the middle" } Then .NET launch an exception. I see output in .NET in these case transform " -> \%22